# Laravel 5.1 PHPUnit 503 error

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Currently stumped on a test that is returning a 503 error for no reason. Running Laravel 5.1 and latest PHPUnit.

**The test:**

```
$this->call('GET', '/about');
$this->assertResponseStatus(200);
```

Fails because it returns a 503 error, other tests (similar GET calls) pass.

If I `dd($this->call())` I can see the entire html response is returned but still has a 503 error attached. No errors in the logs either. The page loads fine in a browser, no 503 error.

**edit:**

```
Route::group(array('after' => 'cache:1440'), function() {
    Route::get('about', 'HomeController@showAbout');
}
```

**edit2:**

```
dd($this->call('GET', '/about'));
```

yields full html+

```
version: "1.1"
statusCode: 503
statusText: "Service Unavailable"
charset: null
```

composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
    "watson/sitemap": "2.0.*",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-httpcache": "0.2.x@dev",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers",
        "app/Models",
        "app/Helpers"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: can u show your routes? Also Laravel 5.1 comes with Laracast integrated its a nice wrapper around phpUnit try to see if that works

Comment: Doesn't the error page contain any information about the error? What about the log file? Errors should always be logged somewhere...

Comment: @ThreeAccents not sure what you mean about laracast integrated, do you have a link? I've attached the route, but it seems fine because I can navigate to the page.

Comment: @SimonSvensson nothing under `storage/laravel.logs` or php logs. On the data dump I can see the entire html is returned but status code is 503. Mind boggling.

Comment: Is your app in maintenance mode? 503 is the error that comes up for that.

Comment: @treeface i don't think it is in maintenance, only one - two test fail the others pass

Comment: What does cache:1440 do?  Make sure everything in that filter is available when testing.  Make sure your cache driver is setup appropriately for the testing environment etc...

Comment: One more thing, if you remove the after filter and run tests again, are you still getting the 503?

Comment: @user3158900 its a filter to cache the page, cache driver set to array. removing the filter yields the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the issue for some reason flushing and clearing the cache did not work for the `barryvdh\laravel-httpcache` library, I had to manually delete everything under `storage/httpcache`